# UIPickerView with attributes string

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

According to Apple's documentation there is a UIPickerView Delegate function called, pickerView(_:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:). However, I've tried to make it work, but I seem to do something wrong here. I hope someone can help me out.

To make thing easy, I have a simple program that presents the contents of two array in two components of a picker view. The program is simply one view controller and one picker view. The code is presented her:

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
var familyNames = [String]()
var fontName = ""
let firstArray = Array(0...99)
let secondArray = Array(0...99)
let fontCount = 0

@IBOutlet weak var samplePickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var fontLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    familyNames = UIFont.familyNames.sorted()
    let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyNames[17])
    fontName = fontNames.first!

    samplePickerView.delegate = self
    samplePickerView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {
        return firstArray.count
    } else {
        return secondArray.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    var rowTitle = ""
    let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 18.0)
    let stringDictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]

    switch component {
    case 0:
        rowTitle = String(format: "%03d", firstArray[row])
    case 1:
        rowTitle = String(format: "%03d", secondArray[row])
    default:
        break
    }

    let returnString = NSAttributedString(string: rowTitle, attributes: stringDictionary as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
    print(returnString)
    return returnString
}
```

}

The picker view should now present the titles in Bradley Hand, so it's easy to spot that is worked. 
Unfortunately, the picker view is not presenting the titles in the attributed string. The string returned by the delegate method is an attributed string, so it should work. The pictures shows this is not the case. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `font` isn't `nil`? You need to pass a font name, not a family name to the `UIFont` initializer.

Comment: What is being logged to the console? Also, you could avoid the cast by declaring string dictionary with the type.

Comment: @rmaddy `familyNames` is [String]

Comment: @Carpsen90 Yes, but is that a **family** names or a **font** names?

Comment: Oh it's a family names, I've got it

Comment: @Maddy, yes I'm sure. You can easily print out the returnString an see that it is not nil.

Comment: @Thomas, this is being logged to the console: NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fd55ae0de20> font-family: \"Bradley Hand\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt";

Comment: @maddy second comment. Yes, familyNames is an array of strings.

Comment: @MacUserT Have you checked that `fontName` is correct?

Comment: @Yury, sorry for the late response. I was traveling. I assume that when I get the family names from Apple and then select the font name from the family name, all given by Apple, I have the font name correct. That's why I used the funny indexing of the array. In a real program I wouldn't normally do that, but I wanted to make sure I would use the font name as given to me by Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After not getting to a solution I requested a DTS at Apple to understand what I was doing wrong. Apparently, I wasn't doing anything wrong, but the method "pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString?" doesn't let you manipulate that much on the attributed string. The answer from Apple was: "UIPickerView’s attributedTitleForRow delegate won’t change the font attribute, but will work for other attributes like font color."

Fortunately, since I wanted to change the font size and font, there is a way to get a different font and font size in the UIPickerView. The solution provided by Apple: "If you want to use all the font attributes available in NSAttributedString, use viewForRow and return a UILabel as an alternative."

The code now looks like this:
    var familyNames = String
    var fontName = ""
    let firstArray = Array(0...99)
    let secondArray = Array(0...99)
    let fontCount = 0

```
@IBOutlet weak var samplePickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var fontLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    familyNames = UIFont.familyNames.sorted()
    let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyNames[17])
    fontName = fontNames.first!

    samplePickerView.delegate = self
    samplePickerView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {
        return firstArray.count
    } else {
        return secondArray.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    var rowTitle = ""
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue

    switch component {
        case 0:
            rowTitle = String(format: "%03d", firstArray[row])
        case 1:
            rowTitle = String(format: "%03d", secondArray[row])
        default:
            break
    }

    pickerLabel.text = rowTitle
    pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 24.0)
    pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center

    return pickerLabel
}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]
This is the manipulation I would like to do with the text in the picker view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem

```
familyNames = UIFont.familyNames.sorted()
```

You get names of **font families**, but `UIFont` initializer takes **font name** as a parameter, not its **family name**. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/1619041-init):

> **familyNames**
>
> Font family names correspond to the base name of a font, such as Times New Roman. You can pass the returned strings to the `fontNames(forFamilyName:)` method to retrieve a list of font names available for that family. **You can then use the corresponding font name to retrieve an actual font object.**

So, if you want to get names of font for a given family name, use the following method. Then you can use them to create a fonts.

```
UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: String)
```

Also, don't access your font family name by a magic index number like `familyNames[17]`, it's a bad approach. You may get out of bounds and that will make your app to crash.

I would store my font name in a constant, like

```
let pickerFontName = "MyAwesomeFont"

// later in your program
let font = UIFont(name: pickerFontName, size: 18.0)
```

Comment: Hi Juri, thanks for the help here. The family name is indeed not the right name to use. And yes, using an index is indeed not the right way to go, but this is not the actual app, it is a demo to test the attributes string for UIPickerView. I have changed the code to the font name, but it still doesn't work.